# String with values mapped from other data frame in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to make a string basing on ids from other columns where the real value sits in a dictionary.

Ideally, this would look like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

region_dict <- tibble(
  id = c("reg_id1", "reg_id2", "reg_id3"),
  name = c("reg_1", "reg_2", "reg_3")
)

color_dict <- tibble(
  id = c("col_id1", "col_id2", "col_id3"),
  name = c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3")
)

tibble(
  region = c("reg_id1", "reg_id2", "reg_id3"),
  color = c("col_id1", "col_id2", "col_id3"),
  my_string = str_c(
    "xxx"_,
    region_name,
    "_",
    color_name
  ))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   region  color   my_string
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    
#> 1 reg_id1 col_id1 xxx_reg_1_col_1
#> 2 reg_id2 col_id2 xxx_reg_2_col_2
#> 3 reg_id3 col_id3 xxx_reg_3_col_3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I know of dplyr's `recode()` function but I can't think of a way to use it the way I want.

I also thought about first using `left_join()` and then concatenating the string from the new columns. This is what would work but doesn't seem pretty to me as I would get columns that I'd need to remove later. In the real dataset I have 5 variables.

I'll be glad to read your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may also be solved with a fuzzyjoin, but based on the similarity in substring, it would make sense to remove the prefix substring from the 'id' columns of each data and do a `left_join`, then create the 'my_string' by `paste`ing the columns together

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
region_dict %>% 
     mutate(id1 = str_remove(id, '.*_')) %>%
     left_join(color_dict %>% 
          mutate(id1 = str_remove(id, '.*_')), by = 'id1') %>% 
     transmute(region = id.x, color = id.y,
        my_string = str_c('xxx_', name.x, '_', name.y))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   region  color   my_string      
#   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>          
#1 reg_id1 col_id1 xxx_reg_1_col_1
#2 reg_id2 col_id2 xxx_reg_2_col_2
#3 reg_id3 col_id3 xxx_reg_3_col_3
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. Your answer is very inspiring. I haven't known `transmute()` exists and it lead me to find `.keep` parameter in `mutate()`. I've got what I needed with `tibble(
  region = c("reg_id1", "reg_id2", "reg_id3"),
  color = c("col_id1", "col_id2", "col_id3")
) %>%
  left_join(region_dict %>% rename_with(~ str_c("region_", .x)), by = c("region" = "region_id")) %>% 
  left_join(color_dict %>% rename_with(~ str_c("color_", .x)), by = c("color" = "color_id")) %>% 
  mutate(my_string = str_c("xxx_", region_name, "_", color_name), .keep = "unused")`